# Simple concise way to compare the length of result lists returned by two functions

Tags: perl

```
sub foos { qw/foo foo/ }
sub bars { qw/bar bar bar/ }
```

What is a good concise way to assert that "the number of items returned by foos() is less than the number of items returned by bars()"?  `foos() < bars()` doesn't work, nor does `scalar(foos()) < scalar(bars())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Concise" is up to you, I guess, but the simplest way is to assign the result to arrays and compare the arrays

```
my @a = foos();
my @b = bars();
print @a < @b;     # prints 1 with the above subs
```

You can also convert the counts by using the `= () =` method:

```
my $foo = () = foos();  # 2
my $bar = () = bars();  # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works as written, but not with the OP's function definitions.  Perhaps it has something to do with how qw// behavior changed a couple of releases back.  Or, there might be an issue with the function being optimized to a constant.

```
sub foos {(1,2,3)}
sub bars {(1,2,3,4)}

if (foos() < bars()) 
 { print 'foos returns fewer elements than bars'}
else
 { print 'foos returns same or more elements than bars'}
```

The following works with the OP's function (or are they constant?) definitions.

```
sub foos { qw/foo foo/ }
sub bars { qw/bar bar bar/ }

if ( (@g=foos) < (@h=bars) ) 
 { print 'foos returns fewer elements than bars'}
else
 { print 'foos returns same or more elements than bars'}
```

Comment: The first example "works" because `bars()` returns `1,2,3,4`, and in scalar context, that list becomes the last element, which is `4`. Which is larger than `3` from `foos()`. This is reported if you `use warnings` when using non-numerical elements in the subs (`Argument "foo" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<)`)

Comment: Hah!  Thanks for the clarification.  (That'll teach me to test code w/o warnings enabled.)

Comment: Testing code without strict and warnings is quite pointless, indeed. And also, I did the same thing -- tried it with numbers -- which is why I knew about it. :)